# Xamarin Listview doesnt follow the rtl direction

Tags: android, xamarin, arabic, right-to-left, farsi

Helly guys. 
Im learning xamarin and trying to make a basic food app for android. This app is in RTL direction. Now i have a Listview in my main content which contains a list of custom layouts. Here is a look at this custom layout. I is RTL in Xamarin Designer windows. 
[image]

And this is the layout axaml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textDirection="rtl">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/rating4"
        android:id="@+id/imgRating"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/defaultthumbnail"
        android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="10,000 تومان"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/foodPrice"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textDirection="rtl" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="نام غذا"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtFoodName"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:text="توضیحات غذا"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:id="@+id/txtFoodDesc" />
    <TextView
        android:text="تاریخ"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
    <TextView
        android:text="آشپز"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtCook"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my main layout which this listview is in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainContentLayout"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainContentListView"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textDirection="rtl" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when i run this this is what i get

[image]

as you can those 2 linearlayouts inside are following the rule of RTL but are inverted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by adding the following in the application's manifest:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    </application>
</manifest>
```

- default emulator and preview didn't work well with "RTL" languages. try to test on real android device or try xamarin live player.
- also some android devices force "ltr" when the android interface language is English,try to change android language to a "RTL' language.

Comment: I will check this asap.

Answer (score 0):

About `android:supportsRtl="true"`, you can refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element), it's default value is false.

From your `layout axaml code`, it displays in VS's Design as:

[image]

But it display in AS's Design as:

[image]

It is same as the result what you have run.

So, there is something wrong with VS's Design.

If I didn't misread your question, what you want to get is:

[image]

So, you need change your `layout axaml code` to below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/pause"
            android:id="@+id/imgRating"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/dapao"
            android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="10,000 تومان"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/foodPrice"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textDirection="rtl" />
    </LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="نام غذا"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtFoodName"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:text="توضیحات غذا"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:id="@+id/txtFoodDesc" />
        <TextView
            android:text="تاریخ"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text="آشپز"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtCook"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thats exactly opposit of what i want to get.
In your first screenshot Vs design shows exactly what i want to get (Thumbnail in left side, Text in rights side) but in runtime its otherway around. And No i dont want to change the position of my controls . cause then it wont be in currect way in english version.

Comment: If my first screenshot Vs design shows is what you want to get, you just need remove `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` in your first `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I know that. thats not what i want